# Combine two matrices row by row

Tags: pytorch

I have two matrices of the size [18,28,28,5,5] and I want to merge them and get a matrix of the size [18,280,140] in the following sense. I take each square 5x5 from the first matrix and put a 5x5 square from the second matrix below it. That way I have 280 (28x5x2) rows and 140 columns (28x5).

Is there a fast way to do it? I've tried with for loops over 28 but it takes a lot of time.

Code example:

```
  for row in range(28):
      for col in range(28):
       C[i,:,row*10:(row+1)*10,col*5:(col+1)*5] = torch.cat((torch.reshape(A[:,row,col,:],[18,5,5]),torch.reshape(B[:,row,col,:],[18,5,5])),dim=1)
```

I'm pretty sure that I can use unsqueeze instead of reshape but that's how I've done it.
Thanks!

Comment: The explanation is a bit confusing. If you take all the 5x5 matrices in the first tensor stack them vertically with the corresponding 5x5 matrices in the second tensor I would expect a result of size `[18.28,28,10,5]`. It's not clear how you get the `[18,281,140]` you refer to. If you post the code you have that performs this operation inefficiently then that would help a lot.

Comment: I added the lines from my code that are inefficient. I will try to explain again - I have 5x5 block from the first matrix and I want to stack one below it from from the second matrix. After that I put another 5x5 block from the first matrix right next to it and another 5x5 block below it from the second matrix. That way I have 280 (5*28*2) rows and 140 (5*28) columns  . 
Thanks for replying.

Comment: Is it  clear? Do you have any idea?